# Progressbar when page is loading in windows phone 8.1 app with caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, progress-bar, caliburn.micro

I need to show the progressbar while a new page is loading.

PageView.xaml

```
<Button Text="NextPage" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action OpenSchedule]"/>
<ProgressBar Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy}" IsIndeterminate="true" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

PageViewModel.cs

```
public void OpenSchedule()
    {
        IsBusy = true;            
        _navigationService.UriFor<ScheduleSummaryViewModel>().Navigate();          
    }
```

The problem is that the progressbar is showed only when the OpenSchedule() method is completed, but the method is completed only when the new page is loaded. I'll need some "refresh" of the page between the two instruction of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Make the task that you want done while the progressbar is loading`asynchronous` so that you can `await` it and have time to show the progressbar loading.